# Using Django admin interface with enumchoicefield

Tags: django, django-models

I'm attempting to use the Django (2.1.3) admin interface with the enumchoicefield package.  All goes well with creating and executing the migration and starting Django, but when I try to add an instance to the model containing the EnumChoiceField I get:

> Exception Type:   TypeError
>   Exception Value:  render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'
>   Exception Location: /home/django/Env/rosella/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py in as_widget, line 93
>   Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
>   Python Version: 3.5.2

Model code:

```
from enumchoicefield import ChoiceEnum, EnumChoiceField
...
class SystemStatus(ChoiceEnum):
    UNKNOWN = 'Unknown'
    OK = 'Ok'
    DOWN = 'Down'

class Monitor(models.Model):
    ...
    status = EnumChoiceField(SystemStatus, default=SystemStatus.UNKNOWN)
```

Question: Does enumchoicefield support the admin interface?
Note: I tried doing enums using django_enumfield, but also ran into problems with the admin interface - error was `'EnumType' object is not iterable`

Comment: Looks like the author was working on the issue: https://github.com/timheap/django-enumchoicefield/commit/aaae373a7d9568ff35aed657891ca317621792cb

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you should use `EnumChoiceField`, as the library does not have any information about supports in Django 2.X. Also it has mentioned that it is using Python 3.4 in [github page](https://github.com/timheap/django-enumchoicefield). Instead, consider choice fields like this:

```
class SystemStatus(object):
    UNKNOWN = 'Unknown'
    OK = 'Ok'
    DOWN = 'Down'
    choices = (
     (UNKNOWN, "Unknown"),
     (OK, 'Ok'),
     (DOWN, 'Down')
    )
```

And use it in Model:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SystemStatus.choices, default=SystemStatus.UNKNOWN)
```